# VSIX XML Visual Studio 2017 Snippets not Recognized

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-snippets, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm getting an error for all our snippets in our VSIX solution when it is installed on a machine.

The error

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\common7\ide\extensions\c0ymtgwu.hw0\teamcodesnippets\Loaders\qnav.snippet: Missing or unspecified Language attribute
```

Our *.pkgdef file looks like

```
[$RootKey$\Languages\CodeExpansions\CSharp\Paths]
"TeamCodeSnippets"="$PackageFolder$"

[$RootKey$\Languages\CodeExpansions\Xml\Paths]
"TeamCodeSnippets"="$PackageFolder$"
```

All our snippets DO have the language attribute

```
<Code Language="XML">
```

But they fail to install under a language. When I am in a general C# (*.cs) file I can see all our snippets popup, even though the the language of them is set to XML.

Any ideas?